# point to point vs web services integration

Tags: integration, webmethods

There were times when organizations used point to point methods to integrate applications which the middle-ware tools helped to avoid by allowing applications to focus on their core area instead of each one of them writing integration logic.

Now the applications are saying that they are using web services for integration and not really need a middle-ware. How can i convince applications that middle-ware can still help in this situation ? According to me web services is just an advanced point to point solution. Is SOA Governance the only selling point here ?

Comment: This question should be asked on http://programmers.stackexchange.com because it's not a programming issue but about a concept. By the way, how is it related to SoftwareAG's WebMethods suite (you used its tag)?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, if you're doing point to point web services, you won't have the possibility to control the message traffic.

With a middleware ESB, the ESB provides facilities to queue messages and control the rate at which messages are consumed.

Furthermore, ESBs (and message broker) provides guaranteed delivery for your messages. So, if you're consumer is down, you don't lose messages.

With point to point web services you'd have to implement a queueing mechanism and guaranteed delivery mechanism within each web service. At that point, you're just reinventing the wheel.

Furthermore, you're putting much more responsibility on the web service consumer or the web service provider to implement routing/orchestration logic. This can get quite expensive if the end point doesn't belong to you but a third party that you will need to pay for changes.

And then what do you do if your company makes an acquisition and the software used by the other company is based on an old technology that doesn't support web services and doesn't have any option to communicate directly with to .NET or Java web service. To make things as painless as possible with minimal impact, the ESB shoulders all the routing/orchestration logic and through its adapters plugs into the other system to retrieve/create/update/delete data.

What makes an ESB rich is its library of adapters. They've been around long enough to have an adapter for pretty much any old and new technologies.

One of the most important thing to do when studying ESB technologies is to make sure that the adapters that you need for now and the foreseeable future are available

Answer (score 0):

I have some idea about this having seen it in my organization.
Lets take the case of what happened in my organization , we had a common middleware earlier but then later applications just like in the aforesaid case told they wanted no middle ware instead could do their own integration logic .
For e.g Oracle said they could OSB to write their logic and so on .
Then came a time when we had lot of ESBs - OSB , Axis , Message Broker and so on .
With the advent of Federated ESBs(Or applications writing integration logics) came their own problems:

1.No singular service registry.

2.Standardization of service design was impossible. e.g Service Contracts written and maintained varied from different teams

3.Service re-usablity was absolutely lost .

4.Technical Debt if OSB version was not supported later - we had to keep seperate migration plans for seperate ESB's

Ultimately , we had to go ahead with just one ESB to avoid this mess and technical debt.

Moreover , with your case where applications write their own integration logic and if they aren't standard ESBs , I forsee another problem . The problem with implementation and standardizatin of integration design pattern say for e.g Publisher Subcriber.
Hope this helps .

Comment: unfortunately almost all packaged applications today has WS capability and they think the integration problem is solved if we talk SOAP :) and I am rather surprised that even in this digital age we still need to convince/sell ESB concept to people

Answer (score -1):

in the age of the internet of things, and within a business domain the internet of capabilities, middleware is relegated to the ESB.  Most internal business interactions want real time point to point.  Consider ReST web services for example.  If I query a resource I don't want it queue, I want a response.   Coupled with the advent of service versioning (that is versioning on the uri) the consumer is insulated for change for a long time.  should you modulate or buffer requests?  that depends!  do your consumer applications mind waiting around for a response for an indeterminate amount of time.  The viewpoints involved are really fire and forget vs. real time integration. in the real time integration scenario if I place an order I want an order number now, not later.  that's point to point.  the service bus has no place in this scenario.  so it depends on your methodology.  but with the advent of ReST the wheels have fallen of the esBus.  one final thought: with all of the networking capabilities we have at our disposal, lpars, VM's, routing; should we be planning integration based on system unavailability?  I don't think so.